# Multiple copies of same static libraries?

Tags: linker, static-libraries

I have one static library named libplatform.a, and two static libraries liba.a and libb.a are built upon libplatform.a. Now I want to create a program named foo, which will be built together with all the three static libraries.

So how many copies of libplatform.a will be kept in the final program foo?

Answer (score 1):

> So how many copies of libplatform.a will be kept in the final program foo?

Not more than one, likely less than one. Only one copy of *some* files in `libplatform.a` will be included in the final executable. Here is an [explanation](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) of how the linker works.